# D3 Map + TopoJSON (mapshaper) showing empty

Tags: d3, topojson, mapshaper

Just started learn D3.js and TopoJSON. I had shapefile files and converted using [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) to TopoJSON, but when I tried on my local server my map showing empty page without any errors. I don't have direction what's going on.

Here my HTML got from a tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Set a style for our data -->
  <style>
  path {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    fill: grey;
  }
  </style>
<body>

  <!-- implementation of the hosted D3- and TopoJson js-libraries -->
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

  <!-- map creation --> 
  <script>
  // canvas resolution
  var width = 1000,
      height = 600;

  // projection-settings for mercator    
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      // where to center the map in degrees
      .center([0, 50 ])
      // zoomlevel
      .scale(100)
      // map-rotation
      .rotate([0,0]);

  // defines "svg" as data type and "make canvas" command
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // defines "path" as return of geographic features
  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  // group the svg layers 
  var g = svg.append("g");

  // load data and display the map on the canvas with country geometries
  d3.json("blok_zona.json", function(error, topology) {
      g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.blok_zona)
            .geometries)
      .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
  });

  // zoom and pan functionality
  /*var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .on("zoom",function() {
          g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
              d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
          g.selectAll("path")  
              .attr("d", path.projection(projection)); 
    });

  svg.call(zoom)*/

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JSON files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcp9iks661rzftx/blok_zona.json?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Finally it's work, is just centering a projection on right value to:

```
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
        .scale(1050)
        .rotate([-120, 0])
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```